# pytest - run tests with customized markers

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-markers

I used customized pytest markers like below,

```
@pytest.mark.test_id("AB-1234")
def test_test1():
    pass

@pytest.mark.test_id("AB-1234")
def test_test2():
    pass

@pytest.mark.test_id("AB-5678")
def test_test3():
    pass
```

Here `test_id` is the marker name and "AB-1234" is the value.
From command line how to run all the tests with marker test_id==AB-1234? I tried different variations with `-m` option but couldn't find a solution.

EDIT: I tried `pytest -m "AB-1234"` but it runs all the tests.

Comment: So what did you try? `pytest -m "AB-1234"` should work.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, I tried `pytest -m "AB-1234"` but it runs all the tests. Is there anything else needed like registering markers or something?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I misread. Your marker is actually `test_id`, so `-m test_id` would work - the marker attribute (e.g. `AB-1234`) is just ignored. If you want different markers, you have to name them something like `test_AB_1234`. Registering the markers makes sense (avoids the warning and potential clashes), but is not needed for it to work.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, here the test_id is jira id, so the idea is to run all the tests with a specific jira id. So there is no way in this marker format (`test_id("AB-1234"`) to filter out tests with a specific jira id? renaming the test is not an option for me.